# overflow:hidden not working on Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I am working on testing a site on all browsers before starting device adapting with media queries.

I have found an issue: when any element is dynamically affected, the `overflow:hidden` property does not work anymore for that element on Chrome.

You can see it here: http://germanalvarez.net/5/

After loading the site, click on the MENU button on the bottom right of the panel, and click on any section:

- If you are in Chrome, the top part of the panel (classified as `.titlePanel`) will no longer remain `overflow:hidden`, so the overflowed part of the icon will go out of the `titlePanel` (see image). This only happens when changing section.
- If you are in Firefox, even after changing section it will remain hidden, so here, it works OK.
  [image: CHROME issue]

I found a supposed solution on the web: style elements on its tag. If you check my code you'll see `.titlePanel` has this opening tag, but it doesn't work either:

```
<div class="panel titlePanel expanded" style="overflow: hidden;">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the use of `position: fixed` :

```
.titlePanel [class^="icon-"]:before, 
.titlePanel[class*=" icon-"]:before {
    font-size: 16em;
    left: 79%;
    line-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 0 50px;
    position: fixed;
}
```

As you're using `fixed`, your pseudo-element is totally out of the flow. It's no longer affected by any `overflow: hidden` on its parents.

To fix it, remove this fixed position and use `absolute` instead :

```
[class^="title-"] {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
[class^="title-"] i {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But the second part of the code is not related to the problem as far as I know zessk, just the first one. Afer changing to absolute it has been fixed.